# DateTime group by date or hours

Tags: c#, .net

01.02.2010 0:00:00 -> 01.02.2010 anytime

01.02.2010 0:00:00 -> 01.02.2010 0:any minutes and seconds

so here is my date :

```
 DateTime x;
```

it's 
01.02.2010 0:00:00
as a string

```
 x.Date.ToString()
```

here I compare date

```
DatarowsForOneDay = dt.Select("DailyRecTime= '" + x.ToString() + "'");
```

So how can I group by date + Hours without care about minutes and seconds.

Comment: I guess I took group by too literally. Did you only want help with formatting?

Comment: I need group... but also this about formatting is a compare method for group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write your own `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>` to only compare the parts of the DateTime you care about. LINQ's GroupBy has an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer`. I had the same problem recently and did just that.

But you would have to call `GroupBy` before converting to strings. If you can't then you might want to create an `IEqualityComparer<string>` and parse the strings back to `DateTime` before comparing.

I don't have the original code with me right now. I re-typed this from memory and did not test it.

```
public class DateAndHourComparer : IEqualityComparer
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        var xAsDateAndHours = AsDateHoursAndMinutes(x);
        var yAsDateAndHours = AsDateHoursAndMinutes(y);

        return xAsDateAndHours.Equals(yAsDateAndHours);
    }

    private DateTime AsDateHoursAndMinutes(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 
                            dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, 
                            dateTime.Minute, 0);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        return AsDateHoursAndMinutes(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I never did the string based version, but it could use the above `DateTime` based code and look something like...

```
public class DateAndHourStringComparer : IEqualityComparer
{
    private readonly DateAndHourComparer dateComparer = new DateAndHourComparer();

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var xDate = DateTime.Parse(x);
        var yDate = DateTime.Parse(y);

        return dateComparer.Equals(xDate, yDate);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Parse(obj);
        return dateComparer.GetHashCode(date);
    }
}
```

I have not tested it, I did not add null checks or format checks. The code is meant to demonstrate the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter with DateTime.ToString(string pattern).
More information @ http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm.

Comment: but then how do you do the group by?